# How to write a SQL CASE statement without selecting the case column?

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

I am trying to get the below CASE statement to work:

```sql
SELECT name
CASE
    WHEN (monthlymaintenance > 100) then 'expensive'
    ELSE 'cheap'
END cost
FROM cd.facilities
```

It fails with the following error:

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "CASE"
  Position: 33

 Query was: SELECT name, monthlymaintenance
CASE
    WHEN (monthlymaintenance > 100) then 'expensive'
    ELSE 'cheap'
END cost
FROM cd.facilities
```

Source of the SQL puzzle is: https://pgexercises.com/questions/basic/classify.html

Comment: You are missing a comma

Comment: And that's a case _expression_.

Comment: Add a comma after name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for this query you are missing a comma after the 'name' column

```
SELECT name,
CASE
    WHEN (monthlymaintenance > 100) then 'expensive'
    ELSE 'cheap'
END cost
FROM cd.facilities
```